# merging multiple queries that have the same core syntax

Tags: sql, sql-server-2012, query-optimization

Sorry for the vague title!

I'm building a web filter where users will be able to click on options and filter down results using MS-SQL 2012

The problem I have is i'm running 4 queries on every selection made to build the filter and 1 for the results.

Ignoring how it can be best coded so I don't have to reload the filter queries every time, I need help in how i can merge the 4 queries that produce the filter options and counts into 1.

The core of the syntax is the same where most of the logic goes to extract the results based on the filtered selection. However, i need to still produce the filters with their counts.

```
        select datePart(yy,p.startDate) year, count(p.personId) itemCount
        from person p
        where p.field1 = something
        and p.field2 = somethingElse...
```

**Is there a way of running the core and producing the filter list and counts (see below) all in one rather than doing each individually?**

Below is an example of 2 of the filters, but there are others that do similar things, either produce a list from existing data or produce a list from based on before, between and after certain dates.

```
--Filter 1 to get years and counts
with annualList as
(
    select a.year
    from table a
    where a.year > 2000 
)
select al.year, isnull(count,0) itemCount
from annualList al
left join (
        select datePart(yy,p.startDate) year, count(p.personId) itemCount
        from person p
        where p.field1 = something
        and p.field2 = somethingElse...
    ) group by datePart(yy,p.startDate) persons
on al.year = persons.year
order by al.year desc;

--filter 2 to get group stats
select anotherList.groupStatus,  groupStatusCounts.itemCount 
from (
    select 'Child' as groupStatus
    union all
    select 'Adult' as groupStatus
    union all
    select 'Pensioner' as groupStatus
) anotherList
left join (
    SELECT personStatus.groupStatus, count(personStatus.personId) itemCount
    FROM ( select p.personId
           case when (p.age between 1 and 17) then 'Child'
           case when (p.age between 18 and 67) then 'Adult'
           case when (p.age > 65) then 'Pensioner'
           end as groupStatus
           FROM person p
           --and some other syntax to calculate the age...
           where p.field1 = something
           and p.field2 = somethingElse exactly as above query...
         ) personStatus
         GROUP BY personStatus.groupStatus
    ) groupStatusCounts
ON anotherList.groupStatus = groupStatusCounts.groupStatus
```

As an example, using the dataset below, from regDate and using a group by I will be able to to get a list of years from 2010-2014 (filter1 code above).

Using the dataofbirth i'll need to 'calculate' the groupStatus using a case. As you can see from the dataofbirth data, I don't have any records where I can identify a pensioner hence the way I wrote filter 2 (see code above), it will give me the filters I need even if I don't have the data to represent it.

Tried to add the code on SQL Fiddle unfortunately it was down last night

```
INSERT INTO personTable
    ([PersonID], [dateOfBirth], [regDate])
VALUES
    (1,  '1979-01-01 00:00:00', '2010-01-01 00:00:00'),
    (2,  '1979-01-01 00:00:00', '2010-01-01 00:00:00'),
    (3,  '1979-01-01 00:00:00', '2011-01-01 00:00:00'),
    (4,  '1979-01-01 00:00:00', '2011-01-01 00:00:00'),
    (5,  '1979-01-01 00:00:00', '2012-01-01 00:00:00'),
    (6,  '1979-01-01 00:00:00', '2012-01-01 00:00:00'),
    (7,  '1984-01-01 00:00:00', '2012-01-01 00:00:00'),
    (8,  '1992-01-01 00:00:00', '2012-01-01 00:00:00'),
    (9,  '2000-01-01 00:00:00', '2013-01-01 00:00:00'),
    (10, '2010-01-01 00:00:00', '2014-01-01 00:00:00')
```

[my example of SQL Fiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!6/1d4e8/11)

The result want to end up with I need it to look like this based on the results shown in Fiddle

```
filter     | Year   | groupStatus 
-----------+-----------+--------
2010       |  0      |  null
2011       |  2      |  null
2012       |  3      |  null
2013       |  0      |  null
2014       |  3      |  null
child      |  null   |  2
adult      |  null   |  6
pensioner  |  null   |  0
```

Thanking you in advance

Answer (score 0):

I may have misunderstood the requirement massively, however I suspect you want to use [`GROUPING SETS`](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb522495%28v=sql.105%29.aspx). As a simple example (ignoring your specific filters) imagine the following simple data set:

```
PersonID | GroupStatus | Year 
---------+-------------+--------
    1    |  Adult      |  2013
    2    |  Adult      |  2013
    3    |  Adult      |  2014
    4    |  Adult      |  2014
    5    |  Adult      |  2014
    6    |  Child      |  2012
    7    |  Child      |  2014
    8    |  Pensioner  |  2012
    9    |  Pensioner  |  2013
   10    |  Pensioner  |  2013
```

From what I gather you are trying to get 2 different summaries out of this data without repeating the query, e.g.

```
GroupStatus | ItemCount
------------+-----------
    Adult   |     5
    Child   |     2
  Pensioner |     3
```

And

```
    Year    | ItemCount
------------+-----------
    2012    |     2
    2013    |     4
    2014    |     4
```

You can get this in a single data set using:

```
SELECT  Year, 
        GroupStatus,
        ItemCount = COUNT(*)
FROM    T
GROUP BY GROUPING SETS ((Year), (GroupStatus));
```

Which will yield a single data set:

```
YEAR    GROUPSTATUS     ITEMCOUNT
------------------------------------
NULL    Adult           5
NULL    Child           2
NULL    Pensioner       3
2012    NULL            2
2013    NULL            4
2014    NULL            4
```

If you wanted to include the full data as well, you can just include a grouping set with all fields e.g. `(PersonID, Year, GroupStatus)`.

**[Examples on SQL Fiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!6/6a496/4)**

**EDIT**

The below query gives the output you have requested:

```
WITH AllValues AS
(   SELECT  TOP (DATEPART(YEAR, GETDATE()) - 2009)
            Filter = CAST(2009 + ROW_NUMBER() OVER(ORDER BY object_id) AS VARCHAR(15)),
            FilterType = 'Year'
    FROM    sys.all_objects o
    UNION ALL
    SELECT  Filter, 'GroupStatus'
    FROM    (VALUES ('child'), ('Adult'), ('Pensioner')) T (Filter)
)
SELECT  v.Filter,
        [Year] = CASE WHEN v.FilterType = 'Year' THEN ISNULL(data.ItemCount, 0) END,
        GroupStatus = CASE WHEN v.FilterType = 'GroupStatus' THEN ISNULL(data.ItemCount, 0) END
FROM    AllValues AS v
        LEFT JOIN
        (   SELECT  [Year] = DATENAME(YEAR, t.RegDate),
                    Age = a.Name,
                    ItemCount = COUNT(*)
            FROM    T
                    LEFT JOIN 
                    (VALUES 
                        (0, 18, 'Child'), 
                        (18, 65, 'adult'), 
                        (65, 1000000, 'pensioner')
                    ) a (LowerValue, UpperValue, Name)
                        ON a.LowerValue <=  DATEDIFF(HOUR, T.dateofbirth, GETDATE()) / 8766.0
                        AND a.UpperValue >  DATEDIFF(HOUR, T.dateofbirth, GETDATE()) / 8766.0
            WHERE   T.PersonID > 2
            GROUP BY GROUPING SETS ((DATENAME(YEAR, t.RegDate)), (a.Name))
        ) AS data
            ON ISNULL(data.[Year], data.Age) = v.Filter;
```

**[Example on SQL Fiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!6/1d4e8/13)**

Comment: The issue is some of the 'filters' (i.e. groupStatus) needs to be 'calculated' and is not in the system for me to group by in the first place. Also in your example the 'filters' returns will only be based what's in the tables. However, if you have data for 2010-2013 but nothing for 2014 the filter will not show 2010,2011,2012,2013 leaving out 2014 and that will need to be shown too.

Comment: Can you post some sample data and expected output into your question please, as I think I have misunderstood your issue.

Comment: updated my post,in your example you have entries for groupStats in the db for Adult, Child and Pensioner. I dont have this information in my db, I only have date of birth so from that I have to calculate the status.

Comment: added example in SQL fiddle.